# node js busboy not emitting events with angular js $http post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, http, busboy

Busboy seems just stuck in there.

I've tested all 3 events(file, field, finish) but nothing was emitted.

My angular code is below.

```
$http({
    method : 'POST',
    url : mublAConfig.server + '/api/v3/user/friend',
    headers : {
        'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization' : access_token
    },
    transformRequest : function(obj) {
        var str = [];
        for (var p in obj) {
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
        }
        return str.join('&');
    },
    data : {
        id : $scope.writes[0].input,
        say : $scope.writes[1].input
    }
}).success(function(data) {
    console.log('Received data : ', data);
}).error(function(data) {
    console.log('Error! ', data);
});
```

all i did with busboy was below

```
req.busboy = new busboy({headers:req.headers});
req.pipe(req.busboy);
req.busboy.on('file', function(field, file, name) {
    console.log('file event');
});
req.busboy.on('field', function(name, value) {
    console.log('field event');
});
req.busboy.on('finish', function() {
    console.log('busboy finished');
});
```

How can i solve it?

Comment: I have a feeling that the manual setting of `Content-Type` and manual data transformation are unnecessary, but can you do `req.on('data', function(d) { console.dir(d.toString()) })` and show what that logs to your console?

Comment: umm.. nothing shown. so problem is in the angular part?

Comment: Just a guess, your content type should propably be multipart/form-data.

Comment: Tried it and i saw an error. Multipart: Boundary not found

Comment: If you're not seeing any data logged to the console, then something else is reading all of the request data before your busboy code. You could additionally verify that form data is sent by checking your browser's network tab in the developer tools.

Comment: sorry. i've put those code after new busboy(). so i tried again, then got all my form data in urlencoded form.

Comment: Do you have a complete, minimal setup you can provide that duplicates the issue? Or at least provide the data logged to the console? If the data is getting to busboy and the data is formatted correctly, there shouldn't be any problem getting `field` events from busboy.

Answer (score 1):

I have completely no idea, but suddenly this problem is solved.
I did just added some test codes. And removed them. Then it works.
Oh god..